# Minimum PSU for 5600G (no dedicated GPU) without compromising the performance?

Tags: pc, power-supply

I have found on shopping sites that small PSUs are little cheaper than 500+ Watts PSU.

So I want to buy the lowest one because I have no plans for adding external GPU.

I would be using 2x8 GB RAMs and Micro ATX motherboard (something like entry level B450 or B550). And I would use only stock cooler and *no overclocking*.

The official docs of this APU says:

> Default TDP: 65W
>
> AMD Configurable TDP (cTDP): 45-65W

I am not sure if there's actually a relation between 65W and the Power Supply I need.

Or if it means the minimum PSU you need for this APU is 65W - I am not really sure.

**I also found** on a site which recommended minimum 300W power supply for this APU without any dedicated GPU. And the recommendation was a little more (350W) if you want to use some entry level GTX GPU like 1050ti.

But they didn't give any reason for this. *But this lead me to conclude that it *can* be used for less than 500W power supply easily.*

**So, I would like to know what minimum range of power supply unit for this APU. So that it gives quite the same performance which a higher PSU like 500 or 600 Watts would give.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enough is enough. If you can get a quality 300W PSU, that will give you more reliability than a cheapo 600W one. Where I live, quality PSU's don't go as low as 300W, the lowest is 400W. Get them from a reputable brand (NOT aliexpress or Gigabyte, Seasonic or Corsair are better) and preferably with 80+ Gold rating.

BTW the power supply never impacts performance, only reliability and stability.

Comment: Yeah I am thinking to buy 400W because they are more easily available as compared to anything lower than that. But thing is, 400W is cheaper than 500W. I would save my money wherever I can.

Can you please clarify the reputable brand sentence? It's a bit confusing where you mentioned the brands.

Comment: When there is not negatively spoken about that brand widely and reviewers use those PSU's, probably safe.

Comment: Ok. And if we want to use a dedicated GPU too, we would need more PSU right?

Comment: Probably yes. For a basic GPU (RX 570) I would reccomend 500W.